How can I take advantage of the way that a Flash memory chip actually works?
What kind of FLASH memory lets me to separate the ERASE and WRITE operations, and lets me directly address memory cells without some controller abstracting away that possibility from me?
For background information, I have read these:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory
microSD card, how many times can I write the same sector?
From the wikipedia article, I understand that actually, while many people think that the amount of WRITEs is limited, that is not true.
Instead, the amount of ERASUREs is limited, but the amount of WRITEs is actually unlimited.
However:

a block ERASURE sets all bits in the block to be a logical 1.
a write (of a byte) does this:

every "0" bit in the byte to be written actually sets one bit in the flash memory to a logical "0" (unless that bit in the FLASH memory is already 0, in which case the write of that bit does nothing).
every "1" bit in the byte to be written actually is a NOP (no operation).



So, if you WRITE a byte value of FF (hexadecimal) = 255 (decimal), such a WRITE operation does nothing.
And, if you do all of the following WRITEs to the same byte address: (values are hexadecimal):
7F
BF
DF
EF
F7
FB
FD
FE
in ANY order, and any of those 8 WRITEs also may be repeated any times, the end result is exactly the same as a single WRITE operation with the byte value 00 (hexadecimal) would be.
However, according to the linked electronics.stackexchange.com question 420469, unfortunately, if I decide to use a MicroSD card or a USB memory stick as my storage media, then in that case, even if the factory that manufactured such a memory device has internally used FLASH memory to implement their product, there is no way for me to take any advantage of the above mentioned facts about FLASH memory.
This means: such MicroSD card or an USB memory sticks unfortunately do not give me the option to separate ERASURE and WRITE operations from each other, and also they typically have a built-in controller with internal wear-leveling that does not let me to even decide myself what exact data address I want to write!
In general filesystem usage this MAY be a good thing - but for a specific usage pattern, this is a bad thing!
My own usage example:
Let's assume that my own usage pattern is to write event data to FLASH memory.
Each event has been stored in a 6-byte (48 bits) area, where:
8 bits (1 BYTE) = event descriptor (=what happened)
39 bits = date/time -stamp (=when that event happened)
1 bits = selector: 0 = "actual date/time" ; 1 = "GetTickCount" (milliseconds passed since the device was last booted/powered on)
Normally, that selector bit is always 0, but if an event happens before the device has been able to successfully get the current date/time from an NTP server (somewhere on internet), then the selector will be 1, and those 39 bits are instead the 39 low bits of what GeTickCount64 returns.
The idea of this is that once the device successfully can get the current date/time from an NTP server, it can retroactively
scan all events already in it's event log, and calculate the date/time at the time that event happened, and re-write the timestamp to be actual date/time and also overwrite the selector bit with "0".
Let's assume a 512-byte (4096 bit) block size in the flash memory.
In 512 bytes, one can store a maximum of 83 events (6 bytes each):
83 * 6 = 498 BYTEs.
Additionally, let's have a bitmap:
"1" = this entry is unused
"0" = this entry is already used
that needs 83 bits, which rounds up to 11 BYTEs.
498 + 11 = 509 BYTEs.
for a block size of 512 bytes, this leaves 3 unused bytes per block.
If the FLASH memory starts in an ERASEd state (all bits "1"), then for example assume one has a memory of 16 million bytes.
This is 31250 blocks (512 bytes each).
The above described event logging system lets me save 2593750 events, and all that consumes just one single "WRITE".
That means: if each block can be written 100000 times, then I still have 99999 times left after saving 2593750 events.
This is possible, because I designed this event storing system so, that starting with an ERASED (= all bits are "1") state, I can write up to 2593750 events, and not do an ERASE / ERASURE operation at all!
Now let's compare this to what would happen with a MicroSD card or an USB memory stick.
Many of these may have a block size of 4096 BYTEs.
And, since these don't even separate the ERASE and WRITE operations, then:
on such a device, storing just ONE event would mean a ERASE/WRITE cycle on one full block (4096 BYTEs).
if I want to save 2593750 events, then the total would be 2593750 ERASE/WRITE cycles, and the internal wear leveling logic would spread these to several individual blocks.
Assuming I have a 32 Gigabyte MicroSD card, and on that, a 16 gigabyte FAT partition used for this purpose ;
the other partition(s) on the same card would be used to store the software running on an embedded device.
16 gigabytes = 3906250 blocks (each block = 4096 bytes).
So the memory requirement just went up from 16 megabytes to 16 gigabytes, and IF the wear leveling logic is really smart, it wrote each block ONE time, when I did save 2593750 events.
Somewhere in the internet I did read, that typically, if one constantly writes to a MicroSD card (32 gigabytes assumed), that card can only last a few months, until one or more blocks get damaged by exceeding the "maximum number of writes".
Either that calculation was done for a very different usage pattern than I have here, or alternatively, those "wear leveling" algorithms are not as smart as some people think.
If there are (on average) 240 events a day, that would mean 87660 events per year.
So my theoretical 2593750 events will last for 29½ years.
So, what kind of a FLASH memory device gives me the opportunity to:

separate the WRITE and the ERASE operations - and NOT "conveniently" mix them into one and the same operation?

Have a direct control, where exactly I will write or what block to ERASE, and not hide that behind some kind of a controller?


Add-on:
Some commenters asked for a context, so here it comes:
Context:
I am developing an application using Ultibo running on Raspberry Pi 4.
Preferably, when an event happens, I'd like to send information about the event to a server over an internet connection.
But: I also need to prepare my application for the unfortunate situation, that the server cannot be successfully connected.
In that case, I need to store the information about the events locally.
In theory, I could just write that information into a file, 6 bytes at a time (the size of information for one event).
But: since there is a filesystem with a cluster size involved, and furthermore, since even a low-level write
(that can bypass the filesystem and write directly to 512-byte disk sectors)
is still subject to the internal controller of the MicroSD card re-locating sectors, so what from Raspberry Pi's viewpoint is sector LBA 2000000, may be whatever sector on the actual flash memory,
relocated every time the internal wear-leveling algorithm of the MicroSD card so decides.
So: I have two major options here:

use the MicroSD card as storage. In this case: How to minimize the harmful effect that
some day the maximum writing times of the MicroSD card may get exceeded, and that typically renders the MicroSD card useless.

Purchase some kind of external memory, and connect it to this Raspberry Pi.
This could even be an USB memory stick, but if so, it is suspectible to the exact same problems as the MicroSD card is.
At least, destroying an USB memory stick leaves the MicroSD card still usable (and bootable), so damaging the data media
in case of an USB memory stick doesn't destroy the bootable media (the MicroSD card).
Another option would be an SPI -connected external flash memory. it could even be the GD25VQ21BTIG Integrated circuit (by GIGADEVICE).



Where did you find the amount of WRITEs is actually unlimited? Looking at the example TI MSP430 Flash Memory Characteristics there is the concept of Cumulative Program Time which results in The same 16-bit flash word cannot be programmed more than twice before the next erase cycle. Writing to one 16-bit word with two byte-wise programming cycles counts as two programming cycles..

Chester: That "unlimited WRITE" was about FLASH memories in general, not any particular model. This is an integral part of my question: what exact FLASH memory chip offers unlimited writes, and only puts a limit on how many times it can be ERASEd.

There are commands for writing and reading from flash memory. Reading and writing is done in blocks which can be single block and mutiple blocks. SD cards are nor flash. The other type of flash is nand flash. Both are different. Its better you refer to reference manual of flash memory of your interest. You also have to initialize the memory with commands before you can write or read from it. This is for sd cards.  Erase is just writing data again or changing the directory.. You would also need a file system to read and write data in a logical manner. Most people use FAT32 or other for this.

this whole question is crying out for context. Is there a specific problem you are trying to solve? If so, what is it? If not - well, what is the question - other than is there some way to squeeze a bit if extra performance out of FLASH because of its way of working? (which honestly is too abstract without a specific problem to solve.)

This really is just a long way of asking "What if I used 'raw' Flash instead of a MicroSD or USB Flash stick for my event logging system"? And the answer is: ok, go ahead and do that. Pick a SPI Flash IC and do it - there's nothing unusual about that. The sort of things you're describing may be new-to-you, but they're really not new-to-the-art If seen these kinds of things done many times before in 'raw' Flash - most recently in a wear-levelling layer which gets inserted between a standard FAT filesystem and the 'raw' Flash.

every "1" bit in the byte to be written actually is a NOP (no operation).
Not true. You can't change an existing '0' bit back to a '1' without an erase operation, and attempting to do so will likely lead to the flash controller raising an error.

@AHiismak That "unlimited WRITE" was about FLASH memories in general Such FLASH memories are entirely imaginary. They are an idea, not a physical device. So, unless you design and fabricate your own FLASH chip, you can forget about unlimited WRITEs. The actual parts always have limits, usually very low.

Is ferroelectric random access memory (F-RAM) a possibility? I'm not sure of the current maximum size of devices, but found CY15B116QN, CY15V116QN which has a size of 16-Mb, and the datasheet says "Virtually unlimited endurance of 1000 trillion (10^15) read/write". Is that sort of size sufficient to buffer events while there is no internet connection?

srl100: I understand the nand flash model as: ERASE a byte = set all bits in the byte to become "1". WRITE a byte = set all those bits where the bit in the data to be written is "0" to zero, and treat each "1" bit in the data byte as a "no operation" - so writing "1" bit should not even try to change a bit from "0" to "1", but any "1" bit in the data will just leave that target bit untouched. ONLY "ERASE" will turn "0" to "1", a WRITE should never even try to do that.

Chester Gillon: The linked (here) page can be understood in a way, that only the count of WRITE/ERASE cycles is limited. So, if I write many times (no erase between) and then do a single ERASE, that should count as exactly ONE WRITE/ERASE cycle.  Link: https://www.techtarget.com/searchstorage/definition/NAND-flash-memory

@AHiismak So in your sequence of writing 7F and then BF, what do you expect the contents of the byte to be after these two writes?

srl100: after either an ERASE or the FLASH byte location being FF (direct from factory), if you first write 7F and the write BF, I'd expect the FLASH byte to become 3F (and the write to be successful, even though the value 3F does not match BF), but that is to be expected, since a WRITE never changes a bit to "1", it can only change to "0" or leave a bit untouched.

SD memory cards ar meant to be part of an operating system, so a file structure is usually employed. There are individual chips available that may work for the application described.
Here is an example of a 16MBit FLASH where individual bytes up to pages can be written on a previously erased page.

Here is a Digi-Key list of 182 possible candidates.

This is very long and (IMHO) completely pointless analysis of the flash functionality.
Let's get back to basic:

all currently available storage technologies have limited amount of write/erase cycles. It means the failure is imminent, although its probability can be negligible, depending on application and MTFF of the specific media.
the wear can be reduced enormously by wear leveling algorithms, often built-in into file system libraries, or even into low level block device drivers. The larger available space is, the more "playing ground" these algorithms have.
in some applications a simple comparison of existing block content with new data to be written and ignoring identical data can reduce the wear without bit-level analysis of each byte.
many file system libraries support automatic marking of bad blocks and excluding them from usable space. If you are writing file system yourself you can support this functionality.
the application can further reduce the chance of critical error by handling write errors and switching to backup files.
finally, in case of dramatic increase of failures or significant reduction of the available non-damaged space an application can indicate an error to the user and prompt to replace storage media, optionally with support of clone operation for old data.

In short, choose the media with good MTFF rating, choose the size with abundant spare space, use libraries with wear levelling and don't bother with internal media workings. If you want to further reduce the chance of failure you have simple application-level methods to do this.
